# How to fire Range Validation after a particular field is updated using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, unobtrusive-validation, razorengine

I have 2 fields total quantity which updates on dropdown selection and a field to enter quantity which should be lesser or equal to the total quantity. Dropdown selection fetches the data via ajax call. I understand that dynamically updated values in the DOM needs to be forced to parse validate again. But it seems not be working . All other validations works as normal in the form.
Similar questions in SO which I have referred to [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902581/unobtrusive-validation-not-working-with-dynamic-content)
Code tried:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">       
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderID, "PurchaseOrderID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.PurchaseOrderID, Model.PurchaseOrders, "--Select--")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.POTotalQuantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.POTotalQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", min = "1", max = Model.POTotalQuantity.ToString() } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpectedDeliveryDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpectedDeliveryDate, "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpectedDeliveryDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult PopulatePODetails(int POID)
    {
        var purchaseOrder = db.PurchaseOrders.Find(POID);

        var poTotalQty = db.PurchaseOrderLineItems.Where(p => p.PurchaseOrderID == purchaseOrder.ID).Sum(q => q.Quantity);

        // Build an anonymous object 
        var data = new
        {
            POTotalQty = poTotalQty

        };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
//Populating PO quantity on PO selection
    $('#PurchaseOrderID').change(function () {

        if (($(this).val() == "") || ($(this).val() == "0")) {
            //need to clear textbox values
            $('#POTotalQuantity').val('');

        }
        else {
            var poId = $(this).val();

            var url = '@Url.Action("PopulatePODetails", "DeliverySchedules")';
            $.getJSON(url, { POID: poId }, function (response) {
                $('#POTotalQuantity').val(response.POTotalQty);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(response));
            });
        }
    });


});
```

Model:

```
  public class DeliveryScheduleVM
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
//omitted other properties 
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("PO Total Qty")]
        public int POTotalQuantity { get; set; }// this is used as the upper limit 
        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your element already exists on the page, so you do not need to re-parse the validator (and doing it for a json value makes no sense anyway)

Comment: Its not clear what your expecting to happen. All you controls will be validated when you submit the form

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm trying to Fire the Range validation for the field Quantity , the min quantity entered shall be 1 and the max value should be from the populated POTotalQty field ( this field is populated on dropdown selection)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control", type = "number", min = "1", max = Model.POTotalQuantity.ToString() } }) , this was the one I was mentioning, say if I give max =5 staticallyit works . but not when that field value is dynamically populated

Comment: Then you cannot use a `[Range]` attribute. You need to use a conditional validation attribute. Show you model with the attributes you currently have

Comment: You could of course update the `max` attribute in the `Quantity` textbox, but that will not give client and server side validation (`min` and `max` attributes have nothing to do with the jquery.validate.js` plugin)

Comment: @StephenMuecke . Thanks .Any workaround for this? Shared the model used. I'm using Range in the Razor View as attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158371/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user2695433).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to clear up some misconceptions you have.

When you reparse the `$.validator`, your instructing `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to parse the DOM and read the `data-val-*` attributes in your form controls (generated by your properties validation attributes) and add the rules to `jquery.validate.js`. That was already done when the form was first loaded, and is only necessary again when you dynamically add new form controls (e.g. via ajax) which your not doing (your control for `Quantity` already exists). In any case, you need to parse the `<form>` element, not a json object. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4/31769058#31769058) for the correct usage.

Second, the `min` and `max` attributes are for HTML-5 validation only and have nothing to do with jQuery validation. In fact they will not even work since `jquery.validate.js` adds the `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute to your `<form>` element since they do not play well together.

What you need for both client and server side validation is a conditional `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable`, and associated scripts so that the value of `Quantity` can be compared with the value of `POTotalQuantity`. For a good guide to writing your own conditional validation attributes, I recommend [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2). In your case you might write an attribute that is used like

```
[Required]
[Bewteen(1, "POTotalQuantity")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

You can also use the conditional validation attributes from the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) plugin if you do not want to write your own.

Download the package (and include the `mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js` script in your view) and decorate you property with

```
[Required]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)] // for minimum value
[LessThanOrEqualTo("POTotalQuantity", ErrorMessage = "The quantity must be less than or equal to the value of POTotalQuantity")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the explaining the concepts in details.. I have used foolproof as per your suggestion.