# ASP.NET Core Client Side Validation With Dynamic Contents

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have some dynamic content that is loaded by AJAX and added to the current page. This content is essentially a form that is rendered on the server-side which includes client-side validation attributes. The problem is, when the resulting form is validated using unobtrusive validation - the original plus the dynamic, AJAX-loaded -, the validation on the form part that came from AJAX does not fire.
Is it possible to include it in the client validation?

Comment: how are you validating  ? using jQuery unobtrusive validate ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question.

Comment: Take a look at this [unobtrusive validation not working with dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902581/unobtrusive-validation-not-working-with-dynamic-content)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to do:

```
//add content to the form
$(form).removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

There is documentation from Microsoft available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#client-side-validation, but it has a small error, on which the `removeData` method is being called on the form element instead of the jQuery wrapping it.