# asp.net core unobtrusive validation with ajax() post

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I am adding a partial view in asp.net core / razor pages using `ajax()`.  When using unobtrusive validation I am not getting the custom error messages nor the field name from the `[Display(Name = "Year of Graduation")]` reference in the error back to the client.  I simply only get "This field is required."

The following code seems to allow the unobtrusive validation to work:

```
$ajax({
  //code removed for brevity
})
.done(function (response) {
                    //LOAD PARTIAL
                    $("#grad-form").html(response);

                    var form = $("#gaform")
                        .removeData("validator")
                        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
});
```

ref:https://stackoverflow.com/a/14982495/2343826

However, I want it to get the name of the field from the data annotation in the client error.  Display Attribute: `[Display(Name = "Year of Graduation")]`

As-is error message on invalid field:

> "This field is required"

But desired outcome is:

> "This Year of Graduation is required."

**Note:** The desired outcome would work fine if it wasn't loaded dynamically with ajax().  (I think I just need to reset `"unobtrusiveValidation"` after `.parse(form)`but I do not know how)

Comment: what does `response` contain? is it the whole form?

Comment: It contains only the partial's html..  #gaform is the entire form.  Thx!

Comment: refreshing the entire form worked fine for me in this project (that also contains angular) https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore.angular. You can check the `website` project at the path /angular/a2. Here is the js file which was mostly jquery https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore.angular/blob/master/Website/wwwroot/bower/js/netcore-angular.js